# Time_ago_in_words is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm having a weird problem. In my rails app, doing: `time_ago_in_words homework.created_at` returns the error:

```
undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

Context:

```
<h3 class="media-heading"><%= homework.title %></h3>
<p>Assigned <%= time_ago_in_words homework.created_at %> ago</p>
```

created_at is defined, with this migration `t.timestamps null: false` (yes, I have ran it), and it's in the database.

When the second line is taken out, the header works.

`homework.created_at` returns this: `2015-03-08 13:45:11 -0500`

Trace:

```
app/views/homeworks/_homework.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_homeworks__homework_html_erb__2140072314140949314_70221661493300'
app/views/welcome/home.html.erb:26:in `block in _app_views_welcome_home_html_erb__3498543795407979710_70221651392200'
app/views/welcome/home.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_welcome_home_html_erb__3498543795407979710_70221651392200'
app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

`homework.created_at.to_time` errors with: `undefined method`to_time' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Could you please provide full backtrace?

Comment: @maxd Added and updated!

Comment: This is only part of backtracke. HTML page with error should have link `Full Trace`. Click it and you will see full backtrace.

Comment: For any case try to output `homework.created_at` without `time_ago_in_words` helper. It shouldn't be nil. Check it.

Comment: @maxd It works perfectly giving me: `2015-03-08 13:45:11 -0500`

Comment: Here is the [full trace](http://pastebin.com/1yCeF3Nb), available for 1 day

Comment: Problem in [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9bb76261d39b59e7e229c80d052ca91a65ff17be/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L74) line. Seems like `from_time` variable is nil. This nil can appear in [line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9bb76261d39b59e7e229c80d052ca91a65ff17be/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L72). So, try to output `homework.created_at.to_time` and check it.

Comment: `undefined method `to_time' for nil:NilClass` +1 of sending a link to the rails source. You. Are. **Amazing**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72527/discussion-between-penne12-and-maxd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(homework.created_at) unless homework.created_at.blank? %>
```

Comment: Homework.created_at always returns the correct value (but not in words). Does't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Wait... never mind, skipped over this question... still not perfect, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that you have a nil value in the time calculation:

```
undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

The method you're using compares two times:

- `from_time` -- this comes from your parameter, i.e. `created_at`
- `to_time` -- this is Rails automatically using `Time.now`.

See the Rails docs for [`time_ago_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words)

The error shows that in the Rails stack, your `from_time` is nil.

The probable cause is that `created_at` is nil.

This cause is consistent with the second error you posted:

```
homework.created_at.to_time #=> 
undefined method to_time' for nil:NilClass`
```

Perhaps you haven't saved the object yet, or `created_at` is getting wiped out somehow, or the object being rendered is different than you expect?

If your goal is to be able to show a new object, or a created object, then one way to fix it is to add `if..then..else` such as:

```
<% if homework.created_at %> 
  <p>Assigned <%= time_ago_in_words homework.created_at %> ago</p>
<% else %>
  <p>Not Yet Assigned</p>
<% end %>
```

Or, if your goal is to always have a `created_at` time, then one way to fix it is to set the time explicitly (and be prepared for Rails to overwrite this), such as:

```
<% homework.created_at ||= Time.now %>
```

Or, save the object, such as:

```
<% homework.save! %>
```

(In my opinion, it's better to do `save!` in the controller, not the view)

Edit... you wrote "I have saved the object (used RubyMine to verify), and created_at is not nil."

That's surprising! You could see if somehow the object that you're rendering is different than you think, such as adding this ERB:

```
<!-- 
  Homework 
  id:<%= homework.id %>
  created_at:<%= homework.created_at %>
-->
```

Or these kind of exceptions:

```
<% homework.id or raise "error in homework id" %>
<% homework.created_at or raise "error in homework created_at" %>
```

You can rule out any issue with the `time_ago_in_words` method by bypassing it, and going directly to the deeper Rails method:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(homework.created_at, Time.now) %>
```

Any errors beyond this are likely IMHO to be due to accidents (i.e. the ERB is not rendering in a typical way, due to some accident in your code beyond this particular issue) or caches (i.e. the ERB is rendering a cached object, or is somehow rendering a different environment, or object, than you expect).

Try this in your ERB:

```
<%= logger.debug("homework id:#{homework.id}" %>
<%= logger.debug("homework created_at:#{homework.created_at}" %>
```

Then look in your log file, and it's likely that you'll see something amiss, such as an `id` that doesn't match what you expect and/or is `nil`, or a `created_at` that is `nil`, or some kind of caching issue that shows the entire ERB file has something amiss and/or is not running the way you would expect.

Also, try detecting the error in whatever ERB is sending the `homework` variable. For example, if you are using a controller that sets a `@homework` variable, and using a higher-up ERB that has a typical controller instance variable, then is calling your ERB partial, try adding this to the higher-up ERB so you can verify the controller is sending the correct `@homework` that you want:

```
<%= logger.debug("@homework id:#{@homework.id}" %>
<%= logger.debug("@homework created_at:#{@homework.created_at}" %>
```

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: I have saved the object (used RubyMine to verify), and `created_at` is not nil.

Comment: Try to check it without RubyMine: `<%= homework.new_record? %>
<%= homework.created_at %>`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, want to join us in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72527/discussion-between-penne12-and-maxd)?